# Cannot find grub to boot Ubuntu after installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I use a ASUS N550JV laptop (UEFI) and I tried to dual boot 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 on it, along side with Windows 8. I have two hard drives and `/dev/sdb` is a SSD so I want to install Ubuntu on it (Windows is also installed on this drive). But when the auto  installation runs, it tries to install grub on /dev/sda, so it fails. So, I made 30GB unallocated space in Windows then used a USB drive with Ubuntu ISO in it. I partitioned the 30GB space as follows:

```
/boot 100MB   ext2 primary
/     8192MB  ext4 logical
/home 20480MB ext4 logical
swap  the rest of space (about 4GB)
```

and I chose `/dev/sdb` as location to install boot loader. The installation run without reporting any error. But when the installation completed and the system rebooted, grub does not appear in the boot options. I went into boot options in BIOS and check efi directory and did not find grub either. What shall I do with situation? Thanks in advance.

p.s. There actually exists two grub 1.99 in efi partition, which are left by unsuccessful installation of Ubuntu 13.10 and Debian 7.5. When I use them, there appears a grub command line, which I have no idea how to use. Is this causing the problems?

Comment: Is secure boot off? What errors did you get when installing Debian 7.5? What errors are you getting now? . If you are running on UEFI then by default the boot loader (grub) will be in /efi /Debian /grub.efi for Debian installations anyway. Then you would need to install rEFInd boot manager to switch between OS's, it may not be quickest but it works well

Comment: If you solved your problem, please, answer your question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two options when I boot: Sandisk and UEFI:Sandisk. Things does not work if I choose the one without UEFI. It will only work if I choose the one with UEFI.